# A word with the same connotation as "bureaucratic"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms, connotation

I have contacted the math department head at my school to ask about some course offerings, and he answered my question. However, he is a busy professor and researcher, so I feel questions about course offerings and such should be directed to an office or so.
I want to ask the department head:

> "For future reference, I don't want to waste your time with such
>   __________ [*bureaucratic*] questions; is there somebody else I should be contacting with such questions?"

The word *bureaucratic* is wrong here. Is there another word which I can use that maintains the same connotation?

Comment: administrative queries.

Comment: You might consider *administrative* or *procedural*, or pick from a list of synonyms for those.

Comment: See also: _mundane_.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you with questions about red tape; is there somebody else etc.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with all the other answers.  I should point out a small mistake in your question:

"...should be directed to an office or so."  The phrase 'or so' is not correct here, you should say
"...directed to an administrator or similar"

"or so" can only be tagged on to a number or quantity when you want to make it approximate, for example:

"How many people came to the party?"  "I should think fifty or so."
"How much sugar should I put in the cake?"  "A cupful or so"

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps **prosaic**, or as @Paul Brinkley suggested **mundane**. They both hold the connotation of boring and unrelated to your professor's work, however they don't specifically connote a sense of office work.

Answer (score 1):

We Believe that ' BUREAUCRATIC ' is by no means wrong here because it relates to system oriented issues for controlling or managing an organization that is operated by a large nos. of officials. But the same has an unsavory connotation of including complicated rules that makes something slow or difficult. It might give a wrong signal to the person spoken to.

Better try these words :

- ROUTINE
- BASIC
- FUNDAMENTAL

All these mean essential foundation or starting points that's to say core components or facts with which dignitories must not unnecessarily be bothered.